# Perfmon how to get "in Use" memory

Tags: performance, powershell, memory, perfmon

If I look in Task Manager, I can see "In Use" memory. [image]

I know that I can grab performance information in `PerfMon`, but I do not know which counter in Perfmon retrieves this value.

I want to write a PowerShell script to find out average memory usage for the past day. PerfMon is the only option that I can think of. Is there a better way to do this in PowerShell?

Comment: I suggest you [google yourself](http://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+perfmon+memory+usage) And read [this for example](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-day-to-day-admin-tasks-monitoring-performance/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Get-Counter -Counter` is the way to get performance counters in PowerShell 2+. "In use" looks like it's the rounded value of `Total Memory - Available`:

```
[math]::Round(((((Get-Ciminstance Win32_OperatingSystem).TotalVisibleMemorySize * 1kb) - ((Get-Counter -Counter "\Memory\Available Bytes").CounterSamples.CookedValue)) / 1GB),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is run the following to get the current:
The `$UsedRAM` variable is what you are looking for.

```
$SystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Name, TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory
    $TotalRAM = $SystemInfo.TotalVisibleMemorySize/1MB
    $FreeRAM = $SystemInfo.FreePhysicalMemory/1MB
    $UsedRAM = $TotalRAM - $FreeRAM
    $RAMPercentFree = ($FreeRAM / $TotalRAM) * 100
    $TotalRAM = [Math]::Round($TotalRAM, 2)
    $FreeRAM = [Math]::Round($FreeRAM, 2)
    $UsedRAM = [Math]::Round($UsedRAM, 2)
    $RAMPercentFree = [Math]::Round($RAMPercentFree, 2)
```

Now we know how to get the current/In Use memory, but getting the average takes some more code. 
Using the `Get-Counter` we can setup a counter of the average, but note that this will only provide the average during the time of testing and doesn't go back in time.

To get a good understanding of the average, I do about 1000 counts. Note this will also consume memory. Depending on the language of the system the formatting can be wrong.

```
$interval = 1 #seconds
$maxsamples = 1000
$memorycounter = (Get-Counter "\Memory\Available MBytes" -maxsamples $maxsamples -sampleinterval $interval | 
select -expand countersamples | measure cookedvalue -average).average
### Memory Average Formatting ###
$freememavg = "{0:N0}" -f $memorycounter
### Get total Physical Memory & Calculate Percentage ###
$physicalmemory = (Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).Sum / 1mb
$physicalmemory - $memorycounter
#$physicalmemory - $freememavg #Depending on the Formatting of your system
```

This can also be done with the CPU and DISK.